# На телефоне не отображается текст после адаптации. На ноуте при уменьшении все четко отображается, а при открытии с телефона текст просто исчезает

Tags: html, css

[**введите сюда описание изображения**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsKfy.png)
LikeKod.github.io

Comment: и Вы предлагаете нам по картинке угадать, что именно происходит?

Comment: Я написал название сайта, который выложен на гитхабе. Я просто даже не предполагаю в чем может быть дело. Менял шрифт, размер текста, границы. И в интернете не нашёл ответа. Вдруг тут кто-то встречался с таким

Comment: css Вы сами писали? посмотрите медиа-запросы: у Вас там на экранах менее 900px задано `display: none` для `.header_row` и `.header_img`. потому и "исчезает"

Comment: Спасибо, что посмотрели мой код) Да, весь код писал сам. Я понимаю о чем Вы говорите, это было мной прописано. Но проблема в другом… если Вы откроете сайт с компьютера, блок .about_text и .cert_heading будут видны полностью, даже при уменьшении экрана. А при открытии с телефона часть текста в этих же блоках просто чудесным образом исчезает.

Comment: На некоторых других телефонах все четко отрабатывает. Думаю, что зависит от операционки и версии ПО. Спасибо за Ваше время!